# remove list elements in a dataframe in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to scala and struggling with these usecase.
How can I remove the elements part of a list from a coloumn in dataframe.I have a list of names and i need to remove the names if it is present in the dataframe.

I have dataframe like

```
utid|description
12342|my name is daniel
2345|my name is harry and i love sports
2122|his wife sofia is my schoolmate
```

and a list list{"harry","daniel"}

and the output should be like

```
utid|description
12342|my name is 
2345|my name is  and i love sports
2122|his wife sofia is my schoolmate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to use `regexp_replace` inbuilt function as

```
val list = List("harry","daniel")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("description", regexp_replace(col("description"), list.mkString("(", ")|(", ")"), "")).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+-----+-------------------------------+
|utid |description                    |
+-----+-------------------------------+
|12342|my name is                     |
|2345 |my name is  and i love sports  |
|2122 |his wife sofia is my schoolmate|
+-----+-------------------------------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful